# Which waterproof shoes?

Tags: commuter, shoes, weather

I am looking for waterproof shoes to use on my daily bike commute for home-office moves. I previously had rain boots, and was happy with them. Nevertheless they quickly started to "break" in the middle of the sole because my feet move when cycling.

What kind of shoes are you using for this purpose, which ones would you recommend?

Note that I don't have clipless pedals.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you have flat pedals/flat pedals with toe-cages. I used full grain leather/ water proof work boots on flat pedals, it was tough to get them in the toe cages though. Just wax the boots weekly, they will keep your feet dry.

Comment: For years (when I was doing all-weather cycling) I used neoprene booties (made for cycling), and they worked as well as anything.  But in a downpour ain't nuttin' gonna keep your feet dry.

Comment: (Note that the neoprene booties can be used with "clipless" pedals, by cutting a suitable hole in the bottom of the bootie.  They are designed to permit this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to French wikipedia, automatic pedals seem to be clipless pedals.

A wide range of manufacturers make waterproof shoe covers (also known as overshoes or booties), for use with both clipless pedal systems as well as your usual set of sneakers (be sure to check out the particular model to see if they're compatible. One designed solely for clipless pedals may be too small for your regular shoes unless you just wear Chucks. Ones which can be used for regular shoes are often marked to work with mountain bike shoes and leisure shoes). They just go over your shoes, and look something like this (not endorsing this particular model necessarily): 
[image: Shoe Cover]

But a lot of people commute with their galoshes on regular old platform pedals for a very long time, so maybe you just need a better pair of galoshes?

A big part of not getting your feet soaked is avoiding water getting to them in the first place, which you typically do by using fenders.

Full fenders with mud guards - a lot of water gets kicked up by your wheels, and this prevents a lot of it getting to your feet in the first place. They also help dirt from the road not get into your drivetrain in the first place which is a nice touch. 
[image: mudguard]

If you're commuting on a race bike or full suspension mountain bike something, you may not have the brake clearance or mounting points to run something like these fenders (they're some set made by Planet Bike, but a lot of manufacturers make similar ones). In this case, you can get something that mounts solely on the down tube on and on the seatpost: 
[image: rear] [image: downtube]

which will go a long way to keeping you dry (but not as much as full fenders).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for my English. I don't have any vocabulary about cycling. it was hard for me to write this post with a lot of mistakes. the rain boots I mentioned are galoshes (but I didn't have this word). If many people are using such shoes to commute, I'll just give a try with new ones.

Comment: And automatic pedals are pedals with clips (pédales automatiques is the french word, so I just translated word by word hopping it will be correct, but it isn't). What is the correct english word for that (I'll fix my question)?

Comment: Regarding waterproof shoe covers, I tried several ones and it was never really waterproof under heavy rain for 45mn, that's why I am looking for "rain boots". In your answer you forgot to past the link of the shoe covers you mentioned.

Comment: Some shoe covers are better than others. pedales automatiques seems to translate to clipless pedals (like Shimano SPD/SPD-SL or Look Keo) according to French wikipedia and google translate.

Comment: Thanks for the clipless pedals. So I don't have that but old plain pedals (sounds very strange that clipless means with "clips", usually the less prefix is used to mean "without" isn't it ;-)). Regarding fenders (fenders and mud guards is the samething, no ?), I totally agree, and already have two full ones (front and rear)

Comment: Clipless pedals are a bit of a quirk of english terminology - they don't have the toe clip like old clipped pedals. As for fenders and mudguards, theres regional ambiguity on what word means what, so I just put up pictures.

Comment: There are different kinds of shoe covers, some made from the same materials as rubber boots. Ones made of rubber would probably be quite water proof.  If you want rubber boots, you might be better off with safety-certified rubber boots, which would have hard sole, which would probably stop the sole from breaking.

Comment: Fenders and mudguards are the same thing.  "Clipless" pedals is a misnomer, but it's one that's too well established to fix.

Comment: So clipped pedals are old clipless pedals, make sense !!! or not ... ;-) Thanks again, but I am now wondering the exact term for what has been called "plain old pedals" in this answer ?

Comment: Probably "platform pedals".

Comment: Fenders and shoe covers are a great combination.  It's amazing the difference good fenders make in keeping your shoes dry.  In addition to the brands suggested elsewhere in this thread, the OP may want to consider Showers Pass as another potential source for shoe covers: http://www.showerspass.com/catalog/accessories/club-shoe-covers

Answer (score 1):

For dry feet I have been using [Taiga Dry-foot gaiters](https://www.taigaworks.ca/cart.php?m=product_detail&p=65) for years now. They are about $50 US. I just replaced the pair I had been abusing for about three years.

They cover the shoe but are open at the bottom so whether you clip in or not you are in business. Wash them as you would any Gore-Tex product, that is with the special detergent. They don't need washing often: I only do mine about monthly if I have been using them a lot, but I guess that is a matter of preference. Washing also frees up the zip if it is sticky from salt and grit.

They are also good for very cold days because they act as windbreakers.

Comment: I neglected to mention they've held back every rain I've ever been in. The only way your feet get wet is if you are in a puddle so deep your pedals are submerged.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the "Muck Boot Company Chore Hi Black" along with waterproof trousers. The Muck Boot is neoprene upper and rubber lower, so it is comfortable when pedaling (i.e., it doesn't hit your shin like cheap rain boots) and I get to work dry. The boot never needs to 'dry' off as it is truly waterproof, and with an 8 mile commute I personally don't have any issues with sweating either. The muck boots are nearly indestructible and show no signs of wear yet. It's the only good solution for commuting in the UK when it rains nearly every day. Goretex shoes get wet and take forever to dry and if you wear waterproof socks the socks still end up completely wet and impossible to dry quickly plus your foot sweats a lot when cycling; most of the cover style gaiters or pull-overs end up being too much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried velotoze http://www.velotoze.com/ and they are quite good.  Not perfect but keep my shoes far drier than any others I've tried.  Socks got a little wet but they're far easier to dry out than shoes.  They are a very tight fit and cater for clipless pedals.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Please note that if you are affiliated with the company that you mention, you [must disclose](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) your affiliation within the body of your post.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pair of Gore-Tex trainers when it's wet.

They keep my feet dry, I walk around normally with them the rest of the day. I don't have clipless pedals, but I do have toeclips which can be easily adjusted for different types of shoe.

They also keep the wind off quite well when it's cold, and have been fine recently when it's been a few degrees below freezing.

Sealskinz waterproof socks are quite good too, but it means you still get wet shoes and it's just easier to just have waterproof footwear.

Good mudguards are also highly recommended for commuting.